# Servers running from chrooted Ubuntu on HP TouchPad?

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, port-forwarding, netcat

The problem: servers appear to be broken inside my Ubuntu chroot. No matter what kind of server I try to run, they all seem unresponsive (VLC server won't respond to client, [mkRemote](http://devbury.com/) doesn't move the cursor, Apache gives an error about binding to port 80 and won't start, etc.).

If I'm not mistaken, what should normally happen inside a chroot is that all ports are shared between the chroot and the host, so if another machine tries to hit the host at port 80, it will still see the chrooted Web server. However, here, that isn't what's happening.

When I run netstat from the chroot, every single process lists a foreign address of 0.0.0.0:*, meaning that the only machine which can act as a client is the local host. This is clearly incorrect and abnormal behaviour, as any process on my primary machine meant to be publicly visible lists a foreign address of :::* (which I assume means that any client can see it from any port).
*Edit: Disregard that; apparently the foreign address only distinguishes between whether it's listening for IPv4 or IPv6 connections, so it doesn't seem relevant here.*

So far, Googling has returned nothing of value, and I'm basically stumped. Any ideas? Could it just be some setting which one of the chroot patch devs enabled by default, or does it seem like a more complicated issue?

Thanks.

More context: http://rootzwiki.com/topic/14682-webos-servers-inside-chrooted-ubuntu/

Comment: Possibly relevant information:
* http://buu700.com/tpbind
* http://buu700.com/tpnetstat
* http://buu700.com/tpnmap

Comment: What are your firewall rules (`iptables -nvL; iptables -t nat -nvL; iptables -t mangle -nvL`)? What traffic does `tcpdump` show?

Comment: * http://buu700.com/tpiptables0
* http://buu700.com/tpiptables1
* http://buu700.com/tpiptables2
* http://buu700.com/tptcpdump

Comment: Ok, I see nothing weird in the iptables output. What were you doing during the `tcpdump` capture? (Without knowing, it's hard to parse.)

Comment: I have an NFS share mounted (which the output was being redirected to) and I have the mkRemote server running, but other than that I just had the thing running on its own for 30 seconds before hitting ctrl+C. I can identify the IPs if that helps: * 192.168.1.1: router * 192.168.1.3: buu700.com server * 192.168.1.5: TouchPad/localhost * 192.168.1.6: laptop

Comment: Please run `tcpdump -n tcp` while you have a server running (VLC, for example) and run a client that tries to access this server. This should show the relevant packets (or lack thereof).

Comment: I enabled the Web interface within the chrooted VLC, then went to 192.168.1.5:8080 from both the webOS browser and my laptop browser. The page showed up fine in the local webOS browser, but just hanged when I tried to see it from my laptop (192.168.1.6). http://buu700.com/tptcpdump0

Comment: Sigh. [Cross-posted on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/376507/how-do-you-run-a-server-with-chrooted-ubuntu-on-the-hp-touchpad); answer accepted there, so closing here

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `0.0.0.0:*` and `:::*` is that the first is IPv4-only and the second is IPv6 (or, more typically, IPv4 *and* IPv6 since there is a compatibility layer).

How are you trying to connect to the server? (if you're using `localhost`, maybe that gets resolved to `::1`, the IPv6 form?) Try connecting using `127.0.0.1` instead. Perhaps they *are* running but are unavailable because you are attempting to use IPv6 to connect.

The other option is that maybe a firewall is preventing access to the ports. Try `ufw disable` (as root) if you have the default Ubuntu firewall installed. Remember that if you are using the tablet on an unprotected network, this may have negative security consequences. ;-)

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks. I've been trying to connect to an mkRemote server and a VLC server using IPv4 from my Android phone (no response from either), so I can't use localhost. I'd try hitting a localhost Web server, but this is what happens when I try to run nginx or Apache: http://buu700.com/tpbind. ufw doesn't appear to be installed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, these may be relevant: http://buu700.com/tpnetstat ; http://buu700.com/tpnmap

Comment: What is the output of `sudo iptables -v -L`?

Comment: * http://buu700.com/tpiptables0
* http://buu700.com/tpiptables1
* http://buu700.com/tpiptables2
* http://buu700.com/tptcpdump

Comment: Have you tried `iptables -F` to clear the firewall rules out? Looks like there are a good number of them. (I didn't look at them in detail though.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mount /proc, /dev etc. ?

```
# mount
```

Try netcat:

```
# nc -v -l 8089
# nc -v 127.0.0.1 8089
```

Check system log files.

Answer (score 1):

People of the future, do not fear. If you've found this question, you've come across a frustrating problem and are looking for a sure-fire solution. Luckily, I have answered this question on a different SE site. It has worked for both the OP and me. It can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/376507/how-do-you-run-a-server-with-chrooted-ubuntu-on-the-hp-touchpad).